# CentOS, libedit-devel not found

Tags: php, centos, centos7, yum, centos8

I'm trying to install sqlsrv (ms sql) PHP drivers per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-red-hat-7

I can get all the pre-reqs installed except php-devel which requires libedit-devel which does not seem to exist.

Where can I get libedit-devel?

Comment: Did you try to manually download from here? https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libedit-devel-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [libedit-devel](https://pkgs.org/download/libedit-devel(x86-64)) lib manually.

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libedit-devel-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -i libedit-devel-3.0-12.20121213cvs.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I have the same problem on centos 8, but there apperas to be nothing at http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8 :(

Comment: @NickWeavers Try this link: https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-powertools-x86_64/libedit-devel-3.1-23.20170329cvs.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 5):

Got this error in Centos 8.

The PowerTools repository is not enabled by default on CentOS 8 / RHEL 8 Linux. This repository contains a number of packages required as dependencies when installing other applications, and mostly building applications from source code.

To be able to enable PowerTools Repository on CentOS 8 / RHEL 8 from command line interface. First install DNF plugins package:

```
sudo dnf -y install dnf-plugins-core
```

Install EPEL repository – PowerTools repository & EPEL repository are best friends. So enable EPEL repository as well.

```
sudo dnf -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
```

Enable PowerTools Repository on CentOS 8 / RHEL 8:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

Confirm it is enabled:

```
sudo dnf repolist
```

Then you can try to download it automatically:

```
sudo yum -y install   libedit-devel
```

https://computingforgeeks.com/enable-powertools-repository-on-centos-rhel-linux/

Comment: Apparently, "powertools" must be lowercase. i.e.
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools